# Flutter APK release wont install on android

Tags: android, flutter, installation, build.gradle, apk

I have application that was working normaly, after when I added flutter downloader package I don't know why the release APK could not be installed on android, it says that package is invalid on installation. When I add flutter_downloader package |I have runed flutter clean pub cache and after installing I got min SDK problem, after that I change it (increased minSdkVersion) to pass build process but this APK isn't installing. (Android 13)
Error message : '***app not installed ads package appears to be invalid***'

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.synisys.svg_samis_mobile"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
//        release {
//            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
//            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
//            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
//            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
//        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Build the APK file and then install it manually using `adb install` command. If it fails you will get an error message, copy the error message and include it in your question (please as text, not as screenshot).

Comment: Make sure your device is using Android 13 SDK above

Comment: Guys I tryed as @Robert's tell me, adb install realy helped me, seems there is signing config issue, i have signed my app and its works. Thank you my brother you really helped me!!!